# Override getter functionality in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to declare a field in dart, and only override the functionality of the getter, but I'm not sure how / if that is possible.

```dart
class Pony {
  String ponyGreeting;
  String ponyName;
  Pony(this.ponyGreeting, this.ponyName);

  String get ponyGreeting => "$ponyGreeting I'm $ponyName!";
}
```

That causes an error, though, because I've already defined "ponyGreeting". I can't just get rid of the field ponyGreeting, because I want to set it using the constructor, and if I made a setter I would have to set that value somewhere, and I don't really want a superfluous property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a private variable alongside the getter:

```dart
class Pony {
  String _ponyGreeting;
  String ponyName;
  Pony(this._ponyGreeting, this.ponyName);

  String get ponyGreeting => "$_ponyGreeting I'm $ponyName!";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that pollutes Pony's in-library api with the _ponyGreeting variable. I guess it's hard to break old habits. (I'm a Java programmer.)

Comment: @CorayThan: The convention in dart is that "_" prefixed variables are considered "private/internal". So convention wise you are not breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @CorayThan You can make Pony a separate library if you want to avoid that. This is a general issue when working with library privacy instead of class privacy. You have to decide appropriate library divisions to achieve your desired level of privacy (some have taken the approach that 1 Dart file = 1 library).

Comment: @Pixel Elephant 1 Dart file = 1 library is an interesting idea, though a bit more extreme than this case warrants, I believe. If Python gets by with no access modifiers, Dart should survive with only one.